# Регулярные выражения в качестве констант

Tags: java

Есть обычная задача на валидацию вводимых данных(код ниже)

Как преобразовать регулярки в константы и обращаться к ним при проверке ?
.matches не работает с Pattern

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter name and last name: ");
    String name = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter phone number: ");
    String num = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter email: ");
    String mail = in.nextLine();

    boolean res1 = name.matches("^([A-Z][a-z]*((\\s)))+[A-Z][a-z]*$");
    if (res1) {
        System.out.println("Name validation successful");
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("Illegal. Name must contains only A-Z, a-z and space");
        }

    boolean res2 = num.matches("(\\+)\\d{12}");
    if (res2) {
        System.out.println("Phone number validation successful");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Illegal. Phone number must contains only numbers and +");
        }

    boolean res3 = mail.matches("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$");
    if (res3) {
        System.out.println("Email validation successful");
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("Illegal. Email address must be in a format: (A-Z,0-9,_.+-)@(A-Z0-9.-).[A-Z]");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, сохраните их в поля класса как `final static String` и используйте сколько нужно:

```
    final static String PATTERN_PHONE = "(\\+)\\d{12}";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String num = "123456789000";

        boolean res2 = num.matches(PATTERN_PHONE);
        if (res2) {
            System.out.println("Phone number validation successful");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Illegal. Phone number in a format " + PATTERN_PHONE);
        }
    }
```